# Как изменить внешний вид формы в qt?

Tags: qt, form

Небольшой вопрос как мне сменить стандартный вид формы в qt на что-то другое ,например в видеоуроке который я смотрю у парня окно такого вида .Как я понял это маковское окно, но можно ли сделать что-то похожее на это .[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

см. QStyleFactory

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);   
qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys(); //доступные
a.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
```

Но. на вашей картинке стиль GTK, он вроде уже не поддерживается. (если не под линем)

где-то встречал ссылки на плагины других стилей

Comment: Вставил ваш код в main.cpp и подключил <QStyleFactory> но тема не изменилась ,что-то еще нужно сделать ?

Comment: При этом выводит три стиля которые можно поставить и fusion там есть .

Comment: попробуйте в конструкторе класса qApp->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));